# Wrong summation in Google Sheet pivot table subgroup using custom formula for calculated field

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a Google Sheet with three separate tabs/sheets. Here's [the minimal working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eehEy3IaqGJRQTegu5B4yLcZQpQIo30x67nzVHj_EZE/edit#gid=1371806271). To see the pivot table's settings 1) log in with a Google account and 2) create a copy. The sheets are:

1. Budget - where I can set some spending limits in set categories
2. Transaction - where I can record transactions with a date and two "accounts" (one category plus one source account, e.g. debit)
3. Spendings - a pivot table where I can see spendings in categories groupped by month

All is well, but I want to have a new column in the Spendings pivot table where I can track allocated spending limits (from the Budget sheet) and another to compare this limit to actual spendings (Difference).

For the two columns I have these custom formule:

1. Budget - `=IFNA(INDEX('Budget'!$1:$1000; MATCH('Account'; 'Budget'!$A$1:$A$1000); MATCH((EOMONTH('Date'; -1) + 1); 'Budget'!$A$1:$AA$1)); "")`
2. Difference - `=IFNA(INDEX('Budget'!$1:$1000; MATCH('Account'; 'Budget'!$A$1:$A$1000); MATCH((EOMONTH('Date'; -1) + 1); 'Budget'!$A$1:$AA$1)) - SUM('Amount'); "")`

Looks ugly, but works! Two caveats, which I don't understand, and hence, these are my quetions:

1. Why the totals (highlighted with red by me) are wrong? They should be $500 and $6,000 respectively, or at least that's my end goal.[image]
2. Why values are shown in the two calculated columns only when I set the "Summarize by" to "Custom"?[image]

Actually, I've just noticed that the grand total is off for the calculated column with the formula as well (showing $1,000 instead of $6,5000.)

Comment: Can you ***manually*** create n' showcase us what the table(+numbers) should be in an ideal scenario for your sample dataset & and some noob explanation for the parts(in table) where you are seeing this difference and all?!

Comment: Well, they should $500 and $6000, or empty, maybe N/A. I'm going to update the question.